# How to reach PHP-Document on Webserver with Adobe AIR HTML/JS/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, air

Following thing: Within my Adobe AIR Application (I use the HTML/JS/jQuery variant, not the flash/flex variant) I want to contact my Web Server where a PHP-File is stored that handles database interaction. So I want my AIR-App to request data from the php file (the db) and show it. But when I make a request with .ajax() the AIR Runtime seems to crash. I think it has something to do with Security Sandboxes but I cant figure out what to do next. How do I allow access to a web server within AIR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the AIR API for accessing URLs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: so you think I'll have to use the AIR API? I thought that maybe theres a setting or something do declare at the beginning to allow direct access